# They think he learns fast or they think he is learning fast?

Tags: present-tense

They think he learns fast or 
They think he is learning fast?

What is correct?

Comment: Either is correct in different contexts, but they mean quite different things. You need to provide more detail to work out which will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Good question.   They are similar.

### He learns fast.

This means that he **learns fast**, in general.   **Learning fast** is a characteristic of him.   He learned fast when he was younger, he learns fast now, and he will probably continue to learn fast in the future.  The sense is that "he is smart".

> *Two teachers are discussing a student.  One says, "I have been watching that boy for two years.  He gains skills very quickly.  He learns fast."*

### He is learning fast.

This means that he **is learning a specific thing, right now, fast**.
This does not mean that he **learns fast**, in general.    (He might learn fast in general, but the speaker is not saying so.)

> *Two teachers are discussing a student.  One says, "That boy is usually confused, but today, he is learning fast."*
>
> *The other one says, "Yes.  And this one just saw multiplication for the first time, and she already understands.  She is learning fast, too."*